# Banach's Contraction Mapping Principle theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

[image]

can you please some one explain me how the highlighted  statement comes

im understanding all but not the last one please

Comment: You should give a reference to the book where you found that: *Introduction to metric spaces and fixed point theory* of Khamis and Kirk I guess.

Comment: @yes it is in the book of an introduction to metric space and fixing point theorey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the inequality above the highlighted one, for every $1\leq n < m$, one can see that
$$\sum_{i=n}^md(T^i,T^{i+1}) \leq \phi(T^n(x))-\phi(T^{m+1})\leq \phi(T^n(x)).$$
Where the last inequality holds because $\phi$ takes values in $\Bbb R^+=[0,\infty)$. Letting $m\to \infty$ gives you the desired expression.

Comment: @Surb.....okay how we can conclude that $\phi(T^n(x))\le \phi(T(x))$?

Comment: @InverseProblem Set $\color{red}{n=1}$, then $\phi(T^n(x))=\phi(T(x))$ and let $\color{red}{m\to \infty}$.

Comment: @surb..thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since $d$ is a metric, and $k$ is in $(0,1)$, we can say that $\varphi$ is a non-negative function. 
Hence what you have by the inequality before is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d(T^i(x),T^{i+1}(x))\leq \varphi(T(x)) - $(something non-negative) which is of course less or equal than $\varphi(T(x))$.

The fact that $\varphi$ is bounded follows from the fact that $T$ is a contraction map.